# Magento 2 - How to display the quantity of each product in cart under the add to cart button in the product tile

Tags: magento2.1.6

I want to display the quantity of each product in cart under the add to cart button in the product tile.

[image: represenation]

**How can we achieve below Figure ?**

Answer (score 2):

add below code in addtocart.phtml

```
<?php
$cartItems = $block->getCartQty();
$defaultQty = ($cartItems[$_item->getId()]['qty']) ?? 0;

$defaultQty = ($sellingFormat != 'kg') ? $defaultQty : number_format($defaultQty,2);
?>


<form data-role="tocart-form_<?= $_item->getId() ;?>" data-bind="scope: 'qty_change_<?= $_item->getId() ;?>'" id="frm_<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>" data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()) ?>" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_id" class="cart-item-id" value="<?= ($cartItems[$_item->getId()]['item_id']) ?? ''; ?>">
        <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
        <button class="action tocart primary decrease <?php if($defaultQty == $qtyIncrementBy) : echo 'delete-qty'; endif; ?> qty_<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>" data-bind="click: decreaseQty"><span class="minus"></span></button>
        <div class="input-text qty">
            <input id="qty_<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>"
                   name="qty"
                   readonly
                   data-bind="value: qty()"
                   type="number"
                   value="<?= $defaultQty ?>"
                   readonly
                   size="4"
                   style="width:50px"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>"
                   class="input-text"
                   data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
            />
            <span class="qty-with-tag">
                <span class="selling-format-qty-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>"><?= $defaultQty ?></span><label><?= ($sellingFormat == 'kg') ? $sellingFormatLabel : '' ?></label>
            </span>
        </div>
        <button class="action tocart primary increase" data-bind="click: increaseQty"><span class="Plus"></span></button>

    </form>
```

create a function getCartQty where it get cart qantities

create qty_change.js

```
define([
'ko',
'uiComponent',
'jquery',
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
```

], function (ko, Component,$,customerData) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({

```
    minicartSelector: '[data-block="minicart"]',
    addToCartButtonSelector: '.action.tocart',
    messagesSelector: '[data-placeholder="messages"]',
    updateCartUrl : BASE_URL+'ffc_checkout/cart/addToCart',
    ajaxRequest: [],

    initialize: function () {
        //initialize parent Component
        this._super();
        this.qty = ko.observable(this.defaultQty.toFixed(this.decimalPoint));
        var self = this;
    },
    decreaseQty: function() {

        var product_id = this.productId;

        if($('#qty_'+product_id).val() == 0) {
            this.qty($('#qty_'+product_id).val());
        }

        var newQty = parseFloat(this.qty()) - this.qtyIncrement;

        if (newQty < 0)
        {
            newQty = 0;

            return;
        }

        this.abortAjaxRequest(product_id);

        if(newQty < parseFloat(this.minCartQty)) {
            newQty = 0;
        }

        var availableQty = window.atob(this.saleableQty);

        if(availableQty < newQty) {
            newQty = parseFloat(availableQty);
        }

        this.addRemoveDeleteClass(newQty);
        $('.selling-format-qty-'+product_id).text(newQty.toFixed(this.decimalPoint));


        this.qty(newQty.toFixed(this.decimalPoint));
        $.cookie('cart_qty['+product_id+']',newQty);

        this.submitForm();

    },
    increaseQty: function() {
        var product_id = this.productId;
        if($('#qty_'+product_id).val() == 0) {
            this.qty($('#qty_'+product_id).val());
        }

        var availableQty = window.atob(this.saleableQty);

        if(availableQty < parseFloat(this.qty()) + this.qtyIncrement) {
            return;
        }


        this.abortAjaxRequest(product_id);

        var newQty = parseFloat(this.qty()) + this.qtyIncrement;

        if(newQty < this.minCartQty) {
            newQty = this.minCartQty;
        }

        this.addRemoveDeleteClass(newQty);
        $('.selling-format-qty-'+product_id).text(newQty.toFixed(this.decimalPoint));


        this.qty(newQty.toFixed(this.decimalPoint));

        $.cookie('cart_qty['+product_id+']',newQty);

        var self = this;

        this.submitForm();
    },

    submitForm: function() {

        var tmpId = "tocart-form_"+this.productId;

        this.ajaxSubmit($('[data-role='+tmpId+']'));
    },

    /**
     * @param {jQuery} form
     */
    ajaxSubmit: function (form) {
        var  formData;

        //$(this.minicartSelector).trigger('contentLoading');

        var self = this;
        var product_id = this.productId;
        formData = new FormData(form[0]);

        this.ajaxRequest[product_id] = $.ajax({
            url: this.updateCartUrl,
            data: formData,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,

            /** @inheritdoc */
            success: function (res) {

                if(form.find('.cart-item-id').val() == '') {
                    form.find('[name="item_id"]').val(res.item_id);
                }

                if(self.qty() ==0) {
                    form.find('.cart-item-id').val('')
                }

                // /** Update tax, discount and save on order */
                // $('#minicart-tax').hide();
                // $('#minicart-discount').hide();
                // $('#save_on_order_text').hide();
                // if(res.tax_amount > 0) {
                //     $('#minicart-tax').show();
                //     $('#minicart-tax-per').html('<span>Tax('+ res.tax_percentage +')</span>');
                //     $('#minicart-tax-amount').html(res.tax);
                // }
                // if(res.discount_amount > 0) {
                //     $('#minicart-discount').show();
                //     $('#minicart-discount-amount').html(res.discount);
                // }
                // if(res.save_on_order > 0) {
                //     $('#save_on_order_text').show();
                //     var saveText = 'You will save AED '+ res.save_on_order +' on this order.';
                //     $('#save_on_order_text').html(saveText);
                // }
            },

            /** @inheritdoc */
            error: function (res) {

            },

            /** @inheritdoc */
            complete: function (res) {
                if (res.state() === 'resolved') {
                    var response = res.responseJSON;
                    if(typeof $('#cart-item-'+response.item_id+'-qty').val() != "undefined"
                        && eval($('#cart-item-'+response.item_id+'-qty').val()) != eval(self.qty()))
                    {
                        self.ajaxSubmit(form);
                    } else {
                        $.cookie('cart_qty['+product_id+']',null);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    },

    disableAddToCartButton: function () {
        var tmpId = "tocart-form_"+this.productId;
        var form = $('[data-role='+tmpId+']');
        var addToCartButton = form.find('.action.tocart');
        addToCartButton.attr("disabled", true);
    },

    enableAddToCartButton: function () {
        var tmpId = "tocart-form_"+this.productId;
        var form = $('[data-role='+tmpId+']');
        var addToCartButton = form.find('.action.tocart');
        addToCartButton.attr("disabled", false);
    },

    abortAjaxRequest: function (product_id) {
        if(this.ajaxRequest[product_id] != null) {
            this.ajaxRequest[product_id].abort();
            this.ajaxRequest[product_id] = null;
        }
    },

    addRemoveDeleteClass: function (newQty) {
        $('.qty_'+this.productId).removeClass('delete-qty');
        if(newQty == this.qtyIncrement) {
            $('.qty_'+this.productId).addClass('delete-qty');
        }
    }

});
```

});

Hope it works for you as I have implemented same feature in my website.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, you want to display the quantity of cart products in your product listing page. Hence, to achieve this, you have to override the block `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` which is used by the `Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml` template.

In the overridden `ListProduct` class , use the dependency injection way to inject the `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` class in order to get the cart items collection. Do not use the model `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` as it is deprecated.

In your overridden `ListProduct` class, write a function to return  the quote items (`$this->yourCheckoutSessionObject->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();`) and get the results in your `list.phtml` file. There in the product collection-loop, provide a condition to check if the current product id is equal to the product id in your cart. If so display the cart item product quantity using `getQty()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What i have to do for updating the in cart field dynamically when the product is added to cart using ajax cart.

Comment: For that, you should use a container (for example <div id="any-id">) for displaying the In Cart field. When you use ajaxCart function , return the latest quantity on the success of ajaxCart function and set  the innerHtml of your In Cart field container (div) with the latest quantity.